# $\rm{Aut}(G)$ is not cyclic when $G$ is not abelian

Tags: cyclic-groups

we have a $G$ which is not abelian and we need to prove that the group of all automorphisms is not cyclic.

any ideas?

Comment: Try this: If $\rm{Aut}(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is an abelian group and If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: we tried using it. but we don't get why the automorpism group is isomorphic to G/Z(G)

Comment: @idan: $$G/Z(G)\cong Inn(G)\le Aut(G)$$with $\;Inn(G)\;$ being the group of *inner automorphisms* of $\;G\;$ .

Comment: got it! thanks!